# Enter/Delete/Backspace not working in Java-applications on Solaris running on VirtualBox

Tags: virtualbox, java, solaris

I have this strange issue with my keyboard in Solaris 10 running on VirtualBox (Windows 7 host). It works fine in the terminal and all native applications but when it comes to all Java-applications my Enter/Delete and Backspace keys does not work.

All other keys seems to be workings as they should, even the Swedish ones.

Anyone got a clue of what could be wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turning off numlock worked for me. Check this: https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=6173972

Answer (score 0):

Set up a quick Java proggy to output the hex value of the input byte(s) everytime a keyboard event registers (stdin would work).

Comment: Thanks for your help but no keyboard events at all are raised for the "broken" keys. So I can't capture them. :/